# Can you use a 9 / 10 speed chainring with an 8 speed chain?

Tags: chainring

Does it matter if you use a chainring which is specified at 9 / 10 speed with a 8 speed chain?

Comment: For single-speed or fixed gear use, or for multi-speed use? If multi-speed, are we talking about an 8-speed cluster? Single or double chainring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about chainring (not sprocket), it should be fine. You should only be worry with an 8- or lower-speed chain on a 9- or more speed freehub.

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Bicycles/Maintenance_and_Repair/Chains/Chain_sizes